# MySql combine records from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to preform a sql command to update rows, and combine rows with matching data.

As an example of what I'm attempting, I have a table as shown below. I want to update all records that have a userEmail = user@user.com to become admin@example.com. If I attempt a simple update I encounter duplicate key errors.

I could work around this by adding some kind of counter as a surrogate key, but I'd rather avoid that option if possible.

Also, as a secondary feature if possible, I'd like to combine the quantity of the records.

What kind of operation can I use for this?

```
Original table
___________________________________________________________________________
userEmail             |productId   |usItemId |quantity|timestamp          |
----------------------|------------|---------|--------|-------------------|
admin@example.com     |111111111111|222222222|      77|2019-04-07 02:19:41|<--
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-07 02:19:41|
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-07 02:19:41|
user@user.com         |111111111111|222222222|      22|2019-04-07 02:19:41|<--
user@user.com         |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-06 05:34:58|
user@user.com         |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-06 05:35:30|



Updated table
___________________________________________________________________________
userEmail             |productId   |usItemId |quantity|timestamp          |
----------------------|------------|---------|--------|-------------------|
admin@example.com     |111111111111|222222222|      99|2019-04-07 02:19:41|<--
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-07 02:19:41|
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-07 02:19:41|
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-06 05:34:58|
admin@example.com     |xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|       1|2019-04-06 05:35:30|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two steps:

```
insert into original (userEmail, productId, usItemId, quantity, timestamp)
    select 'admin@example.com', productId, usItemId, quantity, timestamp
    from original o
    where o.userEmail = 'user@user.com'
    on duplicate key update quantity = values(quantity) + quantity;

delete from original
    where o.userEmail = 'user@user.com';
```